# How to retrieve all record from every table where id = 1 in MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

How do I retrieve all record from every table (Ex: table1, table2, table3, ... tableN ) where id = 1 from single database (EX: database1) in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Let's suppose I have 1 database and in that I have infinite tables (EX. table1,table2, ....,tableN). Is this possible to get all the record from entire database where id=1 on each table? I think it is possible with SQL `information_schema.table` or `information_schema.column`, but I don't know how to use this.

Any help appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Select from each table, union them all,and filter by id, provided number of columns selected in each select should be same and of compatible datatype

Comment: Show table structures. Union is what you are looking for, but wont work if there is a mismatch in datatype in columns order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the undocumented sp_msforeachtable

```
sp_msforeachtable
@command1 = 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id=1',
@whereand = ' And Object_id In (Select Object_id From sys.columns Where name=''id'')'
```

**@command1** is your query. The question mark is a placeholder the stored procedure uses to insert the table name.

**@whereand** limits the search to just tables that have the column named **id**

Comment: Thank it is helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea of MySQL, Use this in db2

```
Select C.NAME,C.ROLLNUMBER from TABLE1 C,TABLE2 A where C.ROLLNUMBER=A.ROLLNUMBER and id = 1 order by C.CIRCLENAME
```

hope this will work too..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mention the tables manually try this.

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3....COLN FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3....COLN FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3....COLN FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=1
:
:
:
UNION ALL

SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3....COLN FROM TABLEN WHERE ID=1
```

Note: The  col1,col2,col3...coln Should Be Same Datatype in All The Mentioned Tables

This for dynamic building of all the tables with id =1

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3..COLN FROM '+TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ID=1 ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,11,'')
```

Note:Your tables must contain the common column i.e ID .change the column names as per you need but all the mentioned columns in select statement should be contain in all of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way would be to generate a dynamic query and executed it to get the required information.

To generate the query you can use the schema information related system tables and feed the data in a fixed format table. i.e. make a fix format tables having a defined column structure. That will help to feed the data. 
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE AllTableData
(
    TableId int,
    TableName nvarchar(250),
    TableData NVARCHAR(max),
    SelectedId int
)
```

Where TableId is the id of table from system table and TableData will contain the concatenated value string of all columns of a table with some separator identifier.

```
;WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT 
        T1.* 
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T1
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T2 ON T2.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE 
        T2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Id'
        AND T1.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
),
DynamicQuery AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS Id,
        CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME,''''),' AS [TableName],',
            CONCAT(' CONCAT(',STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', [' , C.COLUMN_NAME,']' )
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),') AS [TableData]'
                )
                ,', 1 AS [SelectedId] FROM ',   T.TABLE_NAME,' WHERE Id = 1'
            ) [FinalString]
    FROM T
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
   STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + DQ2.FinalString 
          FROM DynamicQuery DQ2
          WHERE DQ2.Id = DQ1.Id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 10, '') [FinalString]
FROM DynamicQuery DQ1
GROUP BY DQ1.Id, DQ1.FinalString
```

I think, this is what you are searching for.